# Parsing Custom Nginx access log using telegraf logparser

Tags: nginx, influxdb, logparser, telegraf

I have defined a custom nginx log format using below template :

```
log_format main escape=none  '"$time_local" client=$remote_addr '
              'request="$request" '
              'status=$status'
              'Req_Header=$req_headers '
               'request_body=$req_body '
               'response_body=$resp_body '
               'referer=$http_referer '
              'user_agent="$http_user_agent" '
               'upstream_addr=$upstream_addr '
               'upstream_status=$upstream_status '
               'request_time=$request_time '
               'upstream_response_time=$upstream_response_time '
               'upstream_connect_time=$upstream_connect_time ';
```

**In return i get the request logged like below**

```
"09/Sep/2019:13:28:39 +0530" client=59.152.52.190 request="POST /api/onboard/checkExistence HTTP/1.1"status=200Req_Header=Headers: accept: application/json
host: uat-pwa.abc.com
from: https://uat-pwa.abc.com/onboard/mf/onboard-info_v1.2.15.3
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
content-type: application/json
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 46
cookie: _ga=GA1.2.51303468.1558948708; _gid=GA1.2.1607663960.1568015582; _gat_UA-144276655-2=1
referer: https://uat-pwa.abc.com/onboard/mf/onboard-info
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
ticket: aW52ZXN0aWNh
businessunit: MF
sec-fetch-mode: cors
userid: Onboarding
origin: https://uat-pwa.abc.com
investorid: 
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36
 request_body={"PAN":"ABCDEGH","mobile":null,"both":"no"} response_body={"timestamp":"2019-09-09T13:28:39.132+0530","message":"Client Already Exist. ","details":"Details are in Logger database","payLoad":null,"errorCode":"0050","userId":"Onboarding","investorId":"","sessionUUID":"a2161b89-d2d7-11e9-aa73-3dba15bc0e1c"} referer=https://uat-pwa.abc.com/onboard/mf/onboard-info user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36" upstream_addr=[::1]:8080 upstream_status=200 request_time=0.069 upstream_response_time=0.068 upstream_connect_time=0.000
```

I am facing issues in writing a parser rule in telegraf logparser section. Once this data is parsed properly, Telegraf can write it into influx DB.

I have tried various solutions online to find a parsing rule but not able to do so as I am new to it. Any assistance will be appreciated.

Thanks and do let me know if any further information is required.